# JSON input for url in Data Table in kibana

Tags: json, kibana-7

[kibana data table edit - advanced - json input - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAded.png)

Hello
I'm having some problems at this part with JSON language....
I want to make that "Split Row" customized as a clickable URL

Can you guys help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: URL field formatter

Stack management -> Index Patterns -> Select index pattern -> Click on the edit icon on the far right of the field and select the URL formatter.

Comment: Hi! Could you use the "Answer your question" button, or mark this as the correct answer? Marking an answer as the correct answer makes sure this question doesn't stay in the pile of questions to be answered, and keeps it clean. More information on how to accept an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you!